# EmberJS has the model data, but why does my template not show the model values properly?

Tags: javascript, python, django, ember.js

I'm learning EmberJS by utilizing the [Ember-CLI](http://www.ember-cli.com/) and powering a small app using DJango ([DJango Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/)).

I'm trying to display a simple list of 'gardens' from my API but the template isn't showing anything other than "id":

My router:

*routes/gardens.js*

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {        
    return this.store.findAll('garden');
  }
});
```

My model:

*models/garden.js*

```
import DS from 'ember-data';    

export default DS.Model.extend({

});
```

My template:

*templates/gardens.hbs*

```
<h2>Gardens</h2>

<ul>
    {{#each garden in model}}
        <li>
            {{garden.name}}
            {{garden.id}}
            {{garden.owner}}
        </li>
    {{else}}
        Nothing here!
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

All I end up seeing is the "id" of the object, everything else is blank:

[image: I only see the id value, the other two properties are not visible.]

What I've found so far is that the garden API response is in fact coming from my Django API just fine as shown in the Chrome Developer console:

[image]

I previously fixed a root element issue with [ember-django-adapter](https://github.com/dustinfarris/ember-django-adapter) and I'm no longer seeing errors relating to that. My next hunch is this adapter is causing another issue, perhaps the DRFSerializer is losing the payload at some other step later on.

Where did my data go?

**Update**

Hard coding the data works just fine. I'm more than certain I'm missing something with the serialization:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {        
        return [
            {
                id : 0,
                name: "Foo",
                owner: "Bar"
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

The template works with the hard-coded model:

[image]

**Update 2**

Seems like I found where the data is going, I'm just unsure why it's happening, some sort of normalization, but the entire payload is ignored. Just the ID is carried over.

In ember-data/lib/system/store/serializer-response.js the **_normalizeSerializerPayload** is converting the payload to a Json API document.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out and boy, do I feel dumb.

I did not realize EmberJS was strict with the model, I had to define the model properly and explicitly:

*models/garden.js*

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    owner:  DS.attr('string'),
});
```

The last screenshot above is from the Ember-Data internals which was copying 'attributes' which are defined in the model. I had zero which lead me to believe the model was to blame.